# sql Calculation on seperate rows in mins

Tags: sql, database

I have a calculation I do in Excel which I now need to be a SQL query. The `Uptime` and `DownTime` are in minutes and there are times where there might be double or triple Uptime rows. I would like to have `Uptime` and `DownTime` calculated in the query.

In Excel, I query the SQL data then I have two columns with `IF` formulas:

```
( =IF([@Status]="Running",IFERROR((C2-[@DateTime])+(C2 - [@DateTime]) *24*60,"0"),"0")
```

and

```
( =IF([@Status]="Running",IFERROR((C2-[@DateTime])+(C2 - [@DateTime]) *24*60,"0"),"0")
```

Results:

```
Status |DateTime | ***DownTime*** | ***UpTime***
Down   | 4/6/2015 14:05 | ***0***        | ***0***
Up     | 4/6/2015 14:04 | ***0***        | ***1.73***
Down   | 4/6/2015 13:08 | ***55.94***    | ***0***
UP     | 4/6/2015 12:49 | ***0***        | ***18.41***
UP     | 4/6/2015 12:39 | ***0***        | ***10***
```

Comment: What do you exactly need to be calculated... ? What do you want as result ?

Comment: (Sorry for double comment) And what do you have exactly in your database ?

Comment: What is C2, @DateTime in relation to your results? SQL would use a case statement in place of your IF in a query. Having a rough schema and some example rows would help! Also, your 2 formulas look identical to me. Was that intentional?

Comment: also you will likely need a LAG function to check the previous row.

Comment: The data in SQL is the Status column and the DateTime Column. What i am looking for is the other 2 columns (DownTime, UpTime). So if i did a query it would skip the newest record and then do the calculations for the other rows.Ex. if the newest row states it is "UP" and its 1:00PM and the next row comes in and it states now it is down and it is 1:10PM i need the row that reads 1:00 PM to state running for 10 min The reason i need to skip the first row is because i don't know how long it is down/up till the next row appears. and i am looking for the data to be in the column based on the status